# Change background image in cake php depending page

Tags: cakephp, background-image, navbar

I have a problem and i don't know how to solve it. I have a background image (in a CCS file) in my navbar-container and i need to change the image when i go on a specific part of the website.
I don't know how to change the background image if my navbar is the same on all the website.

Thank you for reading me and any help is welcome.

the HTML code:

```
<div id='navbar-container'>
  <div class="topnav" id="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li class='navbtn border'>
```

the CSS code:

```
#navbar-container {
  background-image: url("image");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0 0 0 10000px inset;
  min-height: 35vw; }
#navbar-container .container {
  display: flex;
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto; }
#navbar-container .container .logo img {
  padding-top: 3em; }
```

Comment: You'll either need to do something with the navbar code so that it uses a different class (for example) in that specific part of the site, or else change the layout so that it adds something at a higher level in the DOM which your CSS can pick up on (for example, adding a class to the body, which you can then use to override the standard navbar style, like `.navbar { background: whatever } body.admin .navbar { background: other_thing }`).

Comment: Could you please share the HTML Code corresponding to navbar-container as well as the corresponding CSS Rule.

Comment: I have got the idea to add a class to my navbar, but the class was used everytime and not only in the specific page.